# How to concatenate a variable into non string element in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, string, mongodb, express, mean-stack

i am developing a mean stack application and i am required to execute a query in the mongodb that query is db.locations.find({"name":/sometext/}); this query will provide all the results in which it finds "sometext" in name feild.

now i have express code like this

```
app.post('/api/request/test1',function(req,res){
res.contentType('application/json');
console.log(req.body.name);
var a = req.body.name;
var x= /+a+/;
locations.find({"name":x}).toArray(function (err, items) {
res.send(items);
})    
})
```

but this code is not working as var x=/+a+/ gives an error .

the end result i want is like this, suppose the variable a="TEST"
so x must be /TEST/ without single or double quotes or else the mongodb wont catch it.

Thanks.

Comment: What you're *really* trying to do is make a regular expression, I think.

Comment: try to read attentively this https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well thanks to @Pointy i got the answer.

i created a new regular expression by using this

```
var x= new RegExp(req.body.name);
```

so now if the value of req.body.name is TEST, x will have /TEST/ as a result.

Thanks